# C programming, files, linked lists

Tags: c

The program will read your friends from the file and use a linked-list to store your friends’ details.
Please note that you cannot make any assumptions about the number of your friends and
there is no upper limit for the number of friends.

There is my code, it is not working. I used strtok ...

Content of file should be:

```
Name1; Surname1;M;01.06.1990;
Name2;Surname2;F;02.04.1992;
```

And this is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

#include<string.h>

struct Friend{
char  *name;
char  *sur;
char  *gen;
char  *date;
struct Friend *next;
};
struct Friend * initialize(char *);
void display(struct Friend *);
int main()
{
printf("\nsdasda\n");
struct Friend *head;
char fname[100];
printf("Enter the name of file .txt:  \t");
gets(fname);
head=initialize(fname);
display(head);

}
struct Friend * initialize(char *fname){
FILE* fpointer;
char ch;
fpointer = fopen(fname,"r");
if(fpointer == NULL){

    do
    {
        printf("\nFile not found, please enter the name of file again: \t");
        gets(fname);
        fpointer = fopen(fname,"r");
    }while(fpointer == NULL);
}
//FILE IS OPENED
struct Friend *head=(struct Friend*)malloc(sizeof(struct Friend));
struct Friend *t;
t=head;
char line[255];
char sent[2]=";";

while(!feof(fpointer)){
fgets(line,sizeof line,fpointer);
t->name=strtok(line,sent);
t->sur=strtok(NULL,sent);
t->gen=strtok(NULL,sent);
t->date=strtok(NULL,sent);
if(!feof(fpointer)){
t->next=(struct Friend*)malloc(sizeof(struct Friend));
t=t->next;
}
else if(feof(fpointer)){

t->next=NULL;

}

}

return head;

};

void display(struct Friend *head){
puts(head->name);
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You need to malloc memory for the strings in `t->name`, `t->sur`, etc. and copy the strings. Currently, they are all pointing to elements in the `line` array, which will be overwritten on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not a well-formed question if you just say, *here's my code, it's not working*. But you need to explain what you've tried, narrow down the problem, give details onwhat the expected results were, and what you actually observed (specific errors, etc). Ask a more specific question. See the online help for [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of problems here, not sure to be exhaustive:

- `gets` is unsafe and should never be used. Learn how to use `fgets` which is a safer alternative
- `while(!feof(fpointer))` is almost always wrong. After reading last line, `feof` is still false, it will only be true after the first unsuccessful read operation. So the test for end of file must be between the read and the processing of data.
- do not cast `malloc` in C! It is useless and can only hide compiler warnings if you have indirection level errors
- NEVER, EVER assign char pointers inside a re-useable string. You only store an address and erase the content on next read. Allocate memory for each new string or use `strdup` that does it under the hood (BTW, that's probably what cause you program *not to work*).
- always free what you allocate, be it with `malloc` of `strdup` or any other function internally using `malloc`
- always return a sensible value to the environment from main. Real programs are not run from an IDE...